# Libgdx, gradle integration, drag and drop

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I'm trying to install the Gradle plugin for Eclipse in Ubuntu 14.04 from this link

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/gradle-integration-eclipse

But i'm unable to drag and drop to Eclipse. How and where should i use the drag and drop feature in the Eclipse platform?

Answer (score 0):

If you hover the cursor over the install icon you'll see the following tool-tip (black box):

[image]

So all you have to do is open an eclipse instance, then drag & drop the icon to the **workspace**.

If the above method doesn't work you can install it through the eclipse marketplace. Open an eclipse instance, then from menu click Help and select Eclipse Marketplace...

[image]

Wait a few moments for eclipse to contact the marketplace. Type gradle in the search field (1) then click <kbd>Go</kbd> (2) or hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and wait a few moments for the results. Once the search is complete, click <kbd>Install</kbd> (3) and wait for the process to complete.

[image]

Comment: I've tried that several times now. Still nothing happens! What do i do?

Comment: Follow the comment by venta7 in

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22674749/error-when-trying-to-install-gradle-integration-for-eclipse